# Trying to draw a specific shape with recursion, tried every possible way I know how

Tags: recursion, processing

Using processing and recursion, I'm trying to draw a similar shape to this:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/OPf5D.png]

But I feel like I'm losing my mind trying every possible way to draw the shape. This is closest I've gotten: [image: http://i.imgur.com/vCHJG.png]

Plus my code, any help would be appreciated. Thanks:

```
void setup(){
  size(600,600);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  draws(300, 300, 50, 5);
}

void draws(int x, int y, int x2, int num){
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  line (x, y, (x+x2), y); //right
  line(x, y, x, y-50); //right up
  line (x-x2, y, x-(x2*2), y); // left 
  line(x-x2, y, x-x2, y-50); //left up 
  line (x, y-50, x-x2, y-50); //top 

  if(num>0){
    draws(x-x2, y-x2, x2/2, num-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the magic number `50` everywhere? I think you could do this with an `x_start`, `x_end`, `y_start` and `y_end`, where the height and width of the notch are `(x_end-x_start)/3`. You'll also have to think about how to draw over the flat bits that you want to replace with a notch.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Thanks for the help.

Here is the meat of it, everything else was fine:

line(x, y, x, y-x2); //right

line(x-x2, y, x-x2, y-x2); //left

if (num>0) {

```
draws(x-(x2/3), y-x2, x2/3, num-1); // Central one  

draws(x+(x2/1.5), y, x2/3, num-1); // right one  

draws(x-(x2*1.33), y, x2/3, num-1); // left one
```

}

if (num==0) { //If there are no more instances, draw the horzontal lines

```
line (x, y, (x+x2), y); //right

line (x-x2, y, x-(x2*2), y); // left 

line (x, y-x2, x-x2, y-x2); //top
```

}

Answer (score 0):

(Maybe this should be a comment - since it's not a complete answer - but i can't seem to make it)

That said.......

- you are dividing by 2 rather than 3 at each step.
- you need to draw 3 second hierarchy 'draws' each time
- You have the 'y' coordinate right here - but the x coordinate is wrong.
  at a guess.... the hierarchy should be something like....

`

```
if(num>0){

    draws(x, y-x2, x2/3, num-1); // Central one    
    draws(x-x2, y, x2/3, num-1); // Left One   
    draws(x, y, x2/3/2,  num-1); // right one
}
```

`

Thing that makes it slightly difficult is that your coordinates start from the left hand side of the right line.... probably easier to start from either the far left or far right.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is similar to generating a Koch fractal. It's goes something like this:

1. Draw a straight horizontal line.
2. Divide the line into 3 segments.
3. Move middle segment up by the same amount of the size of one segment.
4. Repeat for each segment.

So, our function should basically try to draw this line:

```
           _________
          |         |
          |         |
          |         |
 _________|         |_________
```

Where the process is repeated in turn for each horizontal line.

One simple way I can think of to do this is to simply start with a straight line. Then in each iteration erase the middle of the line and do the up-shift (you can draw a white line on top of the black line).

So, the pseudocode would be something like this:

```
// Pseudocode:

fractal (x_start,x_end, y) {
    // first simply draw a straight line:
    line(x_start,y,x_end,y);

    // divide the line into 3 and push the middle up
    length = x_end-x_start;
    segment_length = length/3;
    x2 = x_start+segment_length;
    x3 = x_start+segment_length*2;
    y2 = y-segment_length;
    erase_line(x2,y,x3,y);
    line(x2,y,x2,y2);  // up
    line(x2,y2,x3,y2); // accross
    line(x3,y2,x3,y);  // down

    // now repeat for each segment
    fractal(x_start,y,x2,y);
    fractal(x2,y2,x3,y2);
    fractal(x3,y,x_end,y);
}
```

So that's the basic working function. Notice that it doesn't stop recursing so the above function will go on infinitely (or until you run out of memory). So the first thing to do is to add a recursion limit:

```
// Pseudocode:

fractal (x_start,x_end, y, limit) {
    //
    // same content as above except the last 3 lines
    //

    limit --;
    if (limit) {
        fractal(x_start,y,x2,y,limit);
        fractal(x2,y2,x3,y2,limit);
        fractal(x3,y,x_end,y,limit);
    }
}
```

That should be a good starting point.

There are other optimizations you can make. For example, you don't actually need to draw the straight line in the beginning since each iteration will basically draw over it again. You only need to draw the horizontal lines at the limit of the recursion. Which means that you don't need to erase the lines that you didn't draw. But I'll leave the implementation of that as an exercise for the reader.